# делегат и AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

В интернете полно примеров где создается 2 класса, один из которых становится делегатом другого. Но я не нащел ни одного примера где делегатом становится AppDelegate. Можете подсказать как реализовать такое на языке objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

У AppDelegate вполне определённая роль – это делегат класса UIApplication, реализующий методы, связанные с жизненным циклом приложения. Добавлять туда сторонние функции – плохая практика, и так делают исключительно из-за того, что помещать код в AppDelegate удобно.

Но если очень надо, то можно так:

```
@protocol MyDelegate
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyDelegate *delegate;
@end

@interface AppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate, MyDelegate>
@end
@implementation
- (void) doSomething
{
  NSLog("%@", @"did something");
}
@end


// Где инициализируете класс
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
obj.delegate = (id<MyDelegate>)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```